# Is it possible to merge these two queries?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm writing a sql query to count objects.  I have about 50 pre-written queries, and each of them is essentially written like so:

```
    "select count(1) from SOME_TABLE where identifier = :ID"
```

I have it in Java.  SOME_TABLE is already written into the query (different for each query).  At runtime, a switch/case determines which **query** to execute and which **ID** to send it.

Essentially, there are various queries which can be called, but **ID** is the only thing that changes inside the queries.

So, if I want to count all the *pinetrees* in a *forest*, I'd send **pineTree as an ID** to a query that counts Tree.  Simple enough.  As I mentioned, there's a giant switch/case which determines TABLE_NAME, ID, and the exact query.

The problem is, I'm trying to count all of the objects of a table, and I'm trying to count them with various IDs.  For example:

```
    query1: "select count(1) from LIST_OF_TOYS where animalId = theListOfIDsfromQuery2"
    query2: "select allThePetIDs from LIST_OF_PETS where ownerId = :myID
```

This is essentially what I'm trying to do.  I want to count all the toys owned by my pets, but there is no direct link between my ID and the LIST_OF_TOYS table.

I know how to do this with two separate queries, but I would strongly prefer to write one query that just takes ownerId as a parameter, so that I can add it to my giant switch/case (and keep my code neat).  I can write the query however I want, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this as a single query and a single argument.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: "..no direct link..." There's your problem.

Comment: Check SQL `IN` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(1) from LIST_OF_TOYS where animalId in (select allThePetIDs from LIST_OF_PETS where ownerId = :myID)
```